# strange error "(22 - 'Invalid argument')" when used with IPv4

Tags: nmap

I have "(22 - 'Invalid argument')" using nmap.
I'V google'd and got https://seclists.org/nmap-dev/
but on that is it talks about IPv6 while I got this error using
IPv4 in no place IPv4 is mensionned, so why am I getting
this weird error ???????????

i entered

nmap --send-eth --release-memory --nsock-engine=epoll --allports --fuzzy --randomize-hosts --log-errors  --max-os-tries=9 -n --reason --append-output --scanflags=URGACKPSHRSTSYNFIN --max-retries=6 --host-timeout=225s --stats-every=10m --ttl=255 --min-hostgroup=5 --max-hostgroup=25 --max-rtt-timeout=60s --scan-delay=250ms --max-scan-delay=25s --stats-every=1 -v5 -sT -sV -A -p 80-82 0.18.0.0

and got
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-17 16:05 CET
NSE: Loaded 148 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 16:05
Scanning 0.18.0.0 [2 ports]
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (0 up), 1 undergoing Ping Scan
Ping Scan Timing: About 0.00% done
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Completed Ping Scan at 16:05, 0.50s elapsed (1 total hosts)
NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.46 seconds

when trying with less arguements nmap -p 80-82 0.18.0.0
got:
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-17 16:24 CET
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.12 seconds

when trying with ncat i got

marc@platinum:~/NCat_test$ nc -vvv 0.18.0.0 80
0.18.0.0: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [0.18.0.0] 80 (http) : Invalid argument
 sent 0, rcvd 0

marc@platinum:~/NCat_test$ nc -vvv 0.18.0.0 81
0.18.0.0: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [0.18.0.0] 81 (hosts2-ns) : Invalid argument
 sent 0, rcvd 0

i still have "Invalid argument" but this time instead of 22 I got the post numbers and service
80 (http)
81 (hosts2-ns)

this raises a few questions
1) does the "Invalid argument" of ncat and nmap relate to the same thing ?
2) how can I make nmap for informative instead of printing 22 ?
3) how can I say that the remote port is really CLOSEd or is it really OPENned and rejecting because of the firewall ?

thank's for your help

Comment: There is a Linux 4.20.0 kernel bug which results nmap in malfunctioning on local network scans,exactly the (22 - 'invalid argument') error for ipv4 as well, So what's your `uname -a` says?

Comment: "strange error" resolved reading RFC 6890 & 1918

thank's